# Draw a cross inside an recognised Object within borders with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, tensorflow.js

working on a Object Recognition app, and want to have a border around the object and a cross that pinpoints to the center. The border is done but not able to create a cross.
Planned to do 2 more boxes inside but in half so they would draw the cross. Is there any idea how to make it more easier?
Using tfjs-models/coco-ssd/
The logic behind it takes the values and divides them by 2

```
const TargetBox = styled.div`
position: absolute;

left: ${({ x }) => x + "px"};
top: ${({ y }) => y + "px"};
width: ${({ width }) => width + "px"};
height: ${({ height }) => height + "px"};

left2: ${({ x2 }) => x2 / 2+ "px"};
top2: ${({ y2 }) => y2 / 2 + "px"};
width2: ${({ width2 }) => width2 / 2 + "px"};
height2: ${({ height2 }) => height2 / 2 + "px"};
```

Then in the logic section where calculations are done

```
const normalizePredictions = (predictions, imgSize) => {
if (!predictions || !imgSize || !imageRef) return predictions || [];
return predictions.map((prediction) => {
  const { bbox } = prediction;
  const oldX = bbox[0];
  const oldY = bbox[1];
  const oldWidth = bbox[2];
  const oldHeight = bbox[3];

  const imgWidth = imageRef.current.width;
  const imgHeight = imageRef.current.height;

  const x = (oldX * imgWidth) / imgSize.width;
  const y = (oldY * imgHeight) / imgSize.height;
  const width = (oldWidth * imgWidth) / imgSize.width;
  const height = (oldHeight * imgHeight) / imgSize.height;

  const x2 = (oldX * imgWidth / 2) / imgSize.width;
  const y2 = (oldY * imgHeight / 2) / imgSize.heigh;
  const width2 = (oldWidth * imgWidth / 2) / imgSize.width;
  const height2 = (oldHeight * imgHeight / 2) / imgSize.height;

  return { ...prediction, bbox: [x, y, width, height, x2, y2, width2, height2]
```

The x2 y2 ..... it stands for the box that will be in half. Will also create x3 y3... for another half box. But for now the Halfs aren't working

What can be changed?

Now it looks like this
[image: Image recognizer]

What result i want
[image: image with the cross]

Comment: what language do you use? CSS? CSS can't do this, it's for styling, not for drawing. javascript? you didn't say that, you said "react". I've added "tensorflow.js" and "javascript" since that seems to be what you are using. -- so you want to draw two lines, is that right? what exactly is the hurdle you are facing in the achievement of that task? what assistance do you require?

Comment: I have the problem of drawing the lines, i thought if add height2 and width2 and move them by 50%, so it will be in the middle. But i have no idea how to code that. Saw that it only uses x, y, width, height but nothing additional.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `before` and `after` pseudo-elements:

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}
.image-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 5px solid green;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}
.overlay:before {
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.overlay:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1573865526739-10659fec78a5"
        alt=""
      />
      <div class="overlay" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```